# How to pass an object value in a form's select field onChange (using React, without Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a react component with a simple form (no redux, just using react-bootstrap for styling)

I'm pulling data from a database in the following form:

```
[
  {
    "id":"123",
    "name":"Amy Pond",
    "age":"22",
    "reputation":22000
  },
  {
    "id":"124",
    "name":"Clara Oswald",
    "age":"24",
    "reputation":35000
 }
 ...
]
```

and putting it into an object:

```
let userlist = [];
userlist = addUsers(this.state.users);
```

I used map to populate a dropdown based on this data, and can correctly set the state of the user to the selected one from the drop down:

```
<FormControl
   id = "user"
   componentClass="select"
   onChange={this.handleChange}
>
   {userlist.map((r , i) =>
     <option
       key={i}
       value={r.name}>
       {r.name}
     </option>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

using handleChange()

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    value: event.target.value,
    // reputation: ???? // here's where I'm running into issues
    // age: ???????  // and here
});
```

My problem is, I need the user's age and reputation in the handleChange function to set their states accordingly. I've tried passing just `r` instead of `r.name` but I get `[object Object]` back.

```
console.log ("Handle Change Value: " + event.target.value);
```

if I try `event.target.value.name` I get `undefined` back.

The only thing that has sort of worked so far, is using JSON.stringify, but I feel like that's not the right way to do this. I've also thought about just searching through the objects once I've gotten just the name, but if there was a lot of objects I think that would be extremely inefficient? I'm also not sure how to do that.

Can anyone please help me find a way to pass these two extra values so I can set the state? Is map even the best way to create the options? I honestly feel like this is such a simple thing, but I'm still new to react and I've been struggling with this for far too long!

Any ideas / changes / comments / way to make this better would be much appreciated! I realize that perhaps using something like redux-form would make this easier, but I'm hoping there's a simple way to do it without that just for now.

**Edit:**
onChange should have been set to `onChange = {this.handleChange}`, just pasted the wrong code from my attempts to troubleshoot. I'm binding this in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I have a small question regarding this same structure. When Im using it like:

`<Animal 
          name = {animal.name} 
          age = {animal.age} 
          clicked = {this.removeAnimal.bind(this, i)}
          setName = {this.setAnimalName.bind(this, i)}
          index = {i}/>`

This whole stuff is within a js map method call's parameter arrow function.
In the `setAnimalName` method I receive the 2nd object as the event object, is it even possible? If you have any idea pls help me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the user ID as the value in each `option`, then in `handleChange` find the user in your `userlist` to access all the user's properties:

```
<FormControl
   id = "user"
   componentClass="select"
   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
>
   {userlist.map((r , i) =>
     <option
       key={i}
       value={r.id}>
       {r.name}
     </option>
  )}
</FormControl>

handleChange(event) {
  const userId = event.target.value;
  const user = userlist.find(u => u.id === userId);
  this.setState({
    value: user
  });
}
```

Also, the way you are passing the `onChange` property might cause issues. It's hard to tell without seeing all your code, but make sure that you pass in a reference to your `handleChange` function (see above in my answer) rather than calling it right there (as in your question: `onChange={this.handleChange()}`, unless your `this.handleChange` function returns a function).

Comment: This worked! Thank you :) 

Followup question:
I'm making my axios call in `componentWillMount()`, and setting state like `this.setState({ users: response.data, usersArray:addUsers(response.data)  });` I need process the data with addUsers() to get only the data that I want. 

I'm currently doing `userlist = addUsers(this.state.users);` in render() because it seems like the raw data isn't received until then. 

in my handleChange, I can't access userlist, so have to use the state list `const user = this.state.userArray.find(u => u.id === userId)`

Do you know how I can do this better?

Comment: You're right to make the axios call in `componentWillMount()`. When you get the response, I would transform your data right there before you add it to the component's state. Once it's in the state, you can access it both in the `render` method (to display the dropdown options) and in the `handleChange` function (to find the selected user by id).

Comment: I have a small question regarding this same structure. When Im using it like: `<Animal name = {animal.name} age = {animal.age} clicked = {this.removeAnimal.bind(this, i)} setName = {this.setAnimalName.bind(this, i)} index = {i}/>` This whole stuff is within a js map method call's parameter arrow function. In the `setAnimalName` method I receive the 2nd object as the event object, is it even possible? If you have any idea pls help me

Answer (score 2):

It could be a problem with the way you've set your event listener, settings `onChange={this.handleChange()}` would cause the listener to fire right away. Using `onChange={this.handleChange}` correctly sets the listener.

```
<FormControl
   id = "user"
   componentClass="select"
   onChange={this.handleChange}>
   {userlist.map((r , i) =>
     <option
       key={i}
       value={r.name}>
       {r.name}
     </option>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more on events.

You can then use `find()` in your event handler to locate the user:

```
handleChange(event) {
  let user = users.find(u => u.name === event.user.name);
  this.setState({user: user});
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, when I try this with the correct `{this.handleChange}` I'm hitting the following error: 
_TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined_

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use option tag attribute and json to encode/decode like this:

```
<FormControl
        id="user"
        componentClass="select"
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    >
        {userlist.map((r, i) =>
            <option
                key={i}
                value={r.id}>
                {r.name}
                data={JSON.stringify(r)}
            </option>
        )}
    </FormControl>;

    handleChange(event)
    {
        if (e.target.options && e.target.selectedIndex) {
            const user = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data');
            this.setState({
                value: user
            });
        }
    }
```